# How to persist state with useSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a custom hook that stores state in the URL query string, building on top of the React-Router `useSearchParams` Hook:

```js
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const decodeSearchParam = (searchParam: string) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(searchParam);
  } catch {
    return searchParam;
  }
};

function useSearchParamsState<T = string>(
  searchParamName: string,
  defaultValue: T,
): readonly [
  searchParamsState: T,
  setSearchParamsState: (newState: T) => void,
] {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const acquiredSearchParam = searchParams.get(searchParamName);
  const searchParamsState = acquiredSearchParam
    ? decodeSearchParam(acquiredSearchParam)
    : defaultValue;

  const setSearchParamsState = (newState: T) => {
    const next = {
      ...Array.from(searchParams.entries()).reduce(
        (o, [key, value]) => ({ ...o, [key]: value }),
        {},
      ),
      [searchParamName]: JSON.stringify(newState),
    };
    setSearchParams(next);
  };
  return [searchParamsState, setSearchParamsState];
}

export default useSearchParamsState;
```

I'm facing an issue I couldn't resolve where when I set two params at once, only the latest is taking into account.

I have a reproduction of the issue in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lezj6t?file=src%2FsearchParams.hooks.ts

In that example if you click on "Set param1" it will set the `searchParams` as `?param1=1`, but then if you click on "Set param2 and param3" it will only set the latest `param3` and not the `param2`, so the `searchParams` will look like this: `?param1=1&param3=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can enqueue two separate `setSearchParams(searchParams => .....)` calls in a row to set separate search parameters, and the search string is updated with both values as expected. This is using ***the same*** `useSearchParams` hook. From what I can tell, using two ***different*** `useSearchParams` hooks leads to a sort of "stale closure" over the previous `searchParams` to update from.

My suggestion here would be to create a React Context provider that can provide the ***same*** `searchParams` and `setSearchParams` to *all* `useSearchParamsState` hooks so they all reference the same closure.

Example:

searchParams.hooks.tsx

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const decodeSearchParam = (searchParam: string) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(searchParam);
  } catch {
    return searchParam;
  }
};

const SearchParamsStateContext = createContext<[
  searchParams: URLSearchParams,
  setSearchParams: SetURLSearchParams
]>([
  new URLSearchParams(""),
  (search: unknown) => {},
]);

const SearchParamsStateProvider = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  return (
    <SearchParamsStateContext.Provider value={[searchParams, setSearchParams]}>
      {children}
    </SearchParamsStateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useSearchParamsState<T = string>(
  searchParamName: string,
  defaultValue: T
): readonly [
  searchParamsState: T,
  setSearchParamsState: (newState: T) => void
] {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useContext(SearchParamsStateContext);

  const acquiredSearchParam = searchParams.get(searchParamName);
  const searchParamsState = acquiredSearchParam
    ? decodeSearchParam(acquiredSearchParam)
    : defaultValue;

  const setSearchParamsState = (newState: T) => {
    setSearchParams(searchParams => {
      searchParams.set(searchParamName, JSON.stringify(newState))
      return searchParams;
    });
  };
  return [searchParamsState, setSearchParamsState];
}

export default SearchParamsStateProvider;
```

```
import SearchParamsStateProvider, {
  useSearchParamsState
} from "./searchParams.hooks";

...
<SearchParamsStateProvider>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<HomePage />}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</SearchParamsStateProvider>
```

HomePage.tsx

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [param1, setParam1] = useSearchParamsState("param1", "");
  const [param2, setParam2] = useSearchParamsState("param2", "");
  const [param3, setParam3] = useSearchParamsState("param3", "");

  const handleClick1 = () => {
    setParam1(1);
  };

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setParam2(2);
    setParam3(3);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Home page</h1>
        <p>
          <button onClick={handleClick1}>Set param1</button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <button onClick={handleClick2}>Set param2 and param3</button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>list of params:</b> param1: {param1}, param2: {param2}, param3:{" "}
          {param3}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-how-to-persist-state-with-usesearchparams]

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's working great!
I don't know if you noticed but there is a typescript error in the line 21: `(search: URLSearchParams) => search,`

Comment: @Croviajo Aye, sorry about that. VScode and intellisense were being quite uncooperative last night. I've addressed that and other highlighted Typescript discrepancies. Cheers.